# how to call camunda rest api from angularJs 1.5.0 and provide basic authentication

Tags: angularjs, rest, camunda

I am new bee to camunda and angular. I want to access a camunda Rest api service in my angular application. and want to provide basic authentication on login..i try with different approach.but fail got CORS error,401 404 unauthorized errors
this is a call

```
 $http.post('http://192.168.100.107:8080/engine-rest',
                    { username: username, password: password })
                        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                            //callback(response);
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                            //callback(response);
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with  

                        });
```

---

this is the cors filter added in camunda server engine-rest

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>    
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Http Basic Authentication Filter -->
   <filter>
    <filter-name>camunda-auth</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.security.auth.ProcessEngineAuthenticationFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>authentication-provider</param-name>
      <param-value>org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.security.auth.impl.HttpBasicAuthenticationProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>rest-url-pattern-prefix</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
      </init-param> 
  </filter>
```

Comment: Could you please provide us your code?

Comment: $http.post('http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/authorization',
     { username: username, password: password })
      .then(function successCallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
       //callback(response);
      
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
       //callback(response);
      });

Comment: Edit your first question to add the code in it

Comment: it is no longer valid